# Bitbucket mandatory reviewers for branch

Tags: bitbucket, required, review

Can I make the user a mandatory reviewer for each PR to master branch ?
For example:

- we have a bucket with **dev**, **qa**, **master** branches
- we have **@user1**, **@user2** **@user3** in out team
- **@user1** is an architect
- we want **@user1** to be automatically assigned as a mandatory reviewer for each PR to **master** branch

I expect every PR to master branch to be approved by architect.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion above will work, although it is not **truly mandatory**. If you don't mind using a paid app , you can test out [Workzone for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211303/workzone-pullrequest-workflow?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview#:%7E:text=and%20Merge%20Process-,Predefined%20Reviewers%20and%20Groups,-Configure%20pre%2Ddefined). (full disclosure, we built this app)

With the option above, you can delete the default reviewing in both the create pull request screen and then again in the review pull request screen.

With Workzone, you can set individuals or groups as default reviews and when attempting to delete them from the pull request screen, they will be added back by Workzone automatically.

There is a bit more info in the [documentation page here (data center)](https://izymes.com/docs/workzone-predefine-pull-request-reviewers/) or [Cloud Here](https://izymes.com/docs/branch-configurations/)

Hopefully that's of some help? Interested to hear your thoughts.

Cheers - Sean

Comment: Yes, I've seen this add-on, I'm not sure I can convince my client to pay for it. Doesn't 'Code Owners for Bitbucket' do the same thing? I like Workzone for it's convenient UI features, but unfrtunately I am looking for a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set @user1 as default reviewer in Repository settings -> default reviewers
2. In Repository settings -> Branch restrictions for "master" -> Merge settings toggle on the "Minimum number of approvals from default reviewers"

Comment: Thank you! I will use this approach even though the reviewers can be removed. The important thing is that even after their deletion the merge is impossible and there is a message as to why it is impossible and who exactly should confirm PR

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

The default reviewers feature in bitbucket will help you to accomplish it.

Go to repository permission => Default reviewers

We have lot of options here such as

1. Assigning default reviewer for all PR (source branch: any and
   destination branch: any)
2. Assigning default reviewer for a single source and any destination
   (source branch: dev and destination branch: any)
3. Assigning default reviewer for a multiple source with same patterns
   and single destination using patterns (source branch: dev* and
   destination branch: any)
4. Assigning default reviewer for single source and single destination
   branch (source branch: dev and destination branch: master)

Here you can assign a single user or many user for approving PR and number of approvals needed to merge the PR

For you:

The source will be Any Branch.
The destination will be master.
Approver will your architect.
Approvals required will be 1

[image]

Make sure to add branch permission and restrict direct push access for all other users expect for your architect.

Go to branch permission => select master branch => prevent all changes expect by, here select your architect's name.

[image]

Now we have a default reviewer for master and only he can make changes to master branch.

This will ensure other users from merging PR or from pushing changes directly to master.

Hope it helps.